# (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [256] vs. [2901,1024]

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been getting this error and i cant figure out the reason. if anyone could help would be great.

I have defined a hybrid model that consists of three sub-models: a CNN and two MLPs. Then, I use a concatenate operation to merge the features from these three models.

this is my model-code:

```
num_filters = 24
kernel_size = [3, 3]
pool_size = [2, 2]
strides = 2
dense_size = 1024
drop_rate = 0.4

def sunset(image_input_dim):
    x_in = keras.Input(shape=image_input_dim)

    # 1
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size, padding="same", activation='relu')(x_in)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size, strides)(x)

    # 2
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 2, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 2, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size, strides)(x)

    # 3
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 4, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 4, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size, strides)(x)

    # 4
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 8, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 8, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size, strides)(x)


    # 5
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 8, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 8, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size, strides)(x)

    # FC
    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(dense_size, activation='relu',name='CNN_Dense1')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(drop_rate)(x)
    y = keras.layers.Dense(dense_size, activation='relu',name='CNN_Dense2')(x)
    #x = keras.layers.Dropout(drop_rate)(x)


    # construct the model
    model1 = keras.Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=y)

    return model1

def lum_mlp(text_input_dim2):
    model2 = keras.Sequential()
    model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_shape=text_input_dim2, name="dense_lum"))
    return model2


def cover_mlp(text_input_dim3):
    model3 = keras.Sequential()
    model3.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_shape=text_input_dim3, name="dense_cover"))
    return model3
```

The three inputs and one output (label) are packed into an HDF5 file. During training, they are read and encapsulated into a dataset.

The following is my code for data loading and training.

```
def day_block_shuffle(times_trainval):
    # Only keep the date of each time point
    dates_trainval = np.zeros_like(times_trainval, dtype=datetime.date)
    for i in range(len(times_trainval)):
        dates_trainval[i] = times_trainval[i].date()

    # Chop the indices into blocks, so that each block contains the indices of the same day
    unique_dates = np.unique(dates_trainval)
    blocks = []
    for i in range(len(unique_dates)):
        blocks.append(np.where(dates_trainval == unique_dates[i])[0])

    # shuffle the blocks, and chain it back together
    np.random.seed(1)
    np.random.shuffle(blocks)
    shuffled_indices = np.asarray(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(blocks)))

    return shuffled_indices


# a cross validation generator function for spliting the dayblock shuffled indices into training and validation

def cv_split(split_data, fold_index, num_fold):
    # randomly divides into a training set and a validation set
    num_samples = len(split_data)
    indices = np.arange(num_samples)

    # finding training and validation indices
    val_mask = np.zeros(len(indices), dtype=bool)
    val_mask[int(fold_index / num_fold * num_samples):int((fold_index + 1) / num_fold * num_samples)] = True
    val_indices = indices[val_mask]
    train_indices = indices[np.logical_not(val_mask)]

    # shuffle indices
    np.random.seed(fold_index)
    np.random.shuffle(train_indices)
    np.random.shuffle(val_indices)

    data_train = split_data[train_indices]
    data_val = split_data[val_indices]

    return data_train, data_val


# a mapping function from the indices to the corresponding features and labels

def data_loader(hdf5_data_path, sample_idx, batch_size=256):
    def mapping_func_py(hdf5_data_path, sample_idx):
        # convert EagerTensor to str or numpy array
        hdf5_data_path = hdf5_data_path.numpy().decode()
        # sort the sample indices as hdf5 requires increasing order index for data retrieval
        sample_idx = sorted(sample_idx.numpy())

        with h5py.File(hdf5_data_path, 'r') as f:
            # read in the data
            images_log = f['trainval']['images_log'][sample_idx]
            lum_log = f['trainval']['lum_log'][sample_idx]
            coverage_log = f['trainval']['coverage_log'][sample_idx]
            pv_log = f['trainval']['pv_log'][sample_idx]

            # normalize image data to [0,1]
            images_log = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(images_log, tf.float32)

            lum_log = tf.convert_to_tensor(lum_log, dtype=tf.float32)

            coverage_log = tf.convert_to_tensor(coverage_log, dtype=tf.float32)

            # convert pv data to tf.tensor
            pv_log = tf.convert_to_tensor(pv_log, dtype=tf.float32)

            return images_log, lum_log, coverage_log, pv_log

    def mapping_func_tf(hdf5_data_path, sample_idx):
        images_log, lum_log, coverage_log, pv_log = tf.py_function(func=mapping_func_py,
                                                                   inp=[hdf5_data_path, sample_idx],
                                                                   Tout=(
                                                                   tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32))
        return (images_log, lum_log, coverage_log), pv_log

    # create the indices dataset
    idx_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sample_idx)
    # shuffle and batch the indices
    idx_ds = idx_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=idx_ds.cardinality().numpy(), seed=0)
    idx_ds = idx_ds.batch(batch_size).repeat().prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    # indices dataset mapping to images and pviance data
    # returning dataset with the following nested structure: (images_log, pv_log), pv_pred
    dataset = idx_ds.map(lambda x: mapping_func_tf(hdf5_data_path, x),
                         num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    return dataset


# ### Model architecture

# define model characteristics
num_filters = 24
kernel_size = [3, 3]
pool_size = [2, 2]
strides = 2
dense_size = 1024
drop_rate = 0.4

# define training time parameters
num_epochs = 1  # (The maximum epoches set to 200 and there might be early stopping depends on validation loss)
num_fold = 2  # 10-fold cross-validation
batch_size = 256
learning_rate = 3e-06

# define hybrid model
sunset_model = models.sunset(image_input_dim)
lum_mlp_model = models.lum_mlp(text_input_dim2)
cover_mlp_model = models.cover_mlp(text_input_dim3)

combinedInput = concatenate([sunset_model.output, lum_mlp_model.output, cover_mlp_model.output])
x_mix = Dense(4, activation="relu", name="dense_mix_a")(combinedInput)
y_out = Dense(1, activation="linear", name="dense_mix_b")(x_mix)
Mixed = Model(inputs=[sunset_model.input, lum_mlp_model.input, cover_mlp_model.input], outputs=y_out)

# ### model training and validation

# generate dayblock shuffled indices
indices_dayblock_shuffled = day_block_shuffle(times_trainval)

# initialize loss history list
train_loss_hist = []
val_loss_hist = []

for i in range(num_fold):

    # construct and compile model for each repetition to reinitialize the model weights
    keras.backend.clear_session()
    model = Mixed
    # model.summary()
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate), loss='mse')

    # implementing 10-fold cross-validation
    print('Repetition {0} model training started ...'.format(i + 1))

    # creating folder for saving model checkpoint
    save_directory = os.path.join(output_folder, 'repetition_' + str(i + 1))
    if not os.path.exists(save_directory):
        os.makedirs(save_directory)

    # training and validation data preparation
    ## generate indices dataset for training and validation
    indices_train, indices_val = cv_split(indices_dayblock_shuffled, i, num_fold)
    num_val_samples = len(indices_val)
    ## load data from dataloader
    ds_train_batched = data_loader(data_path, indices_train)
    ds_val_batched = data_loader(data_path, indices_val, batch_size=500)
    # print(ds_train_batched)

    # define callbacks for training
    ## early stopping rule: if the validation loss stop decreasing for 5 consecutive epoches
    earlystop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=5)
    ## model check point: save model checkpoint for later use
    checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        os.path.join(save_directory, 'best_model_repitition_' + str(i + 1) + '.h5'),
        monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)

    # training the model and record training and validation loss
    history = model.fit(ds_train_batched, epochs=num_epochs, steps_per_epoch=len(indices_train) // batch_size + 1,
                        verbose=1, callbacks=[earlystop, checkpoint], validation_data=ds_val_batched,
                        validation_steps=len(indices_val) // batch_size + 1)
    train_loss_hist.append(history.history['loss'])
    val_loss_hist.append(history.history['val_loss'])

    # saving model training and validation loss history
    np.save(os.path.join(output_folder, 'train_loss_hist.npy'), train_loss_hist)
    np.save(os.path.join(output_folder, 'val_loss_hist.npy'), val_loss_hist)

    # plot training and validation history
    plt.plot(train_loss_hist[i], label='train')
    plt.plot(val_loss_hist[i], label='validation')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

# summary of training and validation results
best_train_loss_MSE = np.zeros(num_fold)
best_val_loss_MSE = np.zeros(num_fold)

for i in range(num_fold):
    best_val_loss_MSE[i] = np.min(val_loss_hist[i])
    idx = np.argmin(val_loss_hist[i])
    best_train_loss_MSE[i] = train_loss_hist[i][idx]
    print('Model {0}  -- train loss: {1:.2f}, validation loss: {2:.2f} (RMSE)'.format(i + 1,
                                                                                      np.sqrt(best_train_loss_MSE[i]),
                                                                                      np.sqrt(best_val_loss_MSE[i])))
print('The mean train loss (RMSE) for all models is {0:.2f}'.format(np.mean(np.sqrt(best_train_loss_MSE))))
print('The mean validation loss (RMSE) for all models is {0:.2f}'.format(np.mean(np.sqrt(best_val_loss_MSE))))
```

And this is the error i have been getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyProject\docu_code\code\modeltrain\SUNSET_nowcast.py", line 266, in <module>
    history = model.fit(ds_train_batched, epochs=num_epochs, steps_per_epoch=len(indices_train) // batch_size + 1,
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model_1/dense_lum/MatMul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "D:\PyProject\docu_code\code\modeltrain\SUNSET_nowcast.py", line 266, in <module>
      history = model.fit(ds_train_batched, epochs=num_epochs, steps_per_epoch=len(indices_train) // batch_size + 1,
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1564, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 993, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 557, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 510, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 667, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dense.py", line 241, in call
      outputs = tf.matmul(a=inputs, b=self.kernel)
Node: 'model_1/dense_lum/MatMul'
Detected at node 'model_1/dense_lum/MatMul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "D:\PyProject\docu_code\code\modeltrain\SUNSET_nowcast.py", line 266, in <module>
      history = model.fit(ds_train_batched, epochs=num_epochs, steps_per_epoch=len(indices_train) // batch_size + 1,
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1564, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 993, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 557, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 510, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 667, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1097, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dense.py", line 241, in call
      outputs = tf.matmul(a=inputs, b=self.kernel)
Node: 'model_1/dense_lum/MatMul'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [256] vs. [2901,1024]
     [[{{node model_1/dense_lum/MatMul}}]]
     [[mean_squared_error/cond/else/_1/mean_squared_error/cond/remove_squeezable_dimensions/cond_1/pivot_t/_92/_39]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [256] vs. [2901,1024]
     [[{{node model_1/dense_lum/MatMul}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_2584]
```

It seems that the error in Python indicates a problem with the dimensions not matching for matrix multiplication (`MatMul`) in the dense layer of the MLP. This could be due to an issue with either the model configuration or the way the data is loaded.But it is not clear how to solve the issue Thank you for the help in advance...

Comment: What's your code for the `cover_mlp`?

Comment: oh,sorry,my mistake. I have updated the code for cover_mlp, and in fact, it is the same as lum_mlp

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).